# Eloquent Relation - Relation of a Relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

I have three tables: `User`, `Client`, `Position`. The workflow is as follows:

1. A `client` creates its own set of `positions`.
2. A `client` adds the `users` to its administration, and then assigns `positions` to them
3. A `user` can belong to multiple different `clients`.

So the relationship between these tables would be:

- `Client` to `Position` : One-to-Many
- `Position` to `User` : Many-to-Many
- `Client` to `User` : Many-to-Many

So currently, my models is as follows:

```
Class User extends Eloquent {
    public function clients() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Client');
    }

    public function positions() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Position');
    }
}

Class Client extends Eloquent {
    public function users() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

    public function positions() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Position');
    }
}

// The Position model is not included, since it doesn't make sense to start from a position
```

So, say a `User` belongs to two `Clients`, and they have different `Positions` for each of these `Clients`. An example would be:

- I have two clients: Sony and Microsoft
- I have two users: John and Mike.
- Microsoft has positions: Developer and Engineer.
- Sony has positions: Marketing and Finance.
- John works at Microsoft as Developer.
- Mike works at Microsoft as an Engineer and at Sony as a Finance guy.

I want to get Mike's positions at Microsoft only. Right now, the only way I know how to do this is as follows:

```
$c_id = $Microsoft_Id;
$u_id = $Mike_Id;
Client::find($c_id)
        ->users()
        ->whereId($u_id)
        ->with(['positions' => function($query) use ($c_id) 
               {
                   $query->whereClientId($c_id);
               }
        ])
        ->get();
```

Is there a way I can perform this task within the model itself? This would like more intuitive if I were to just say:

```
Client::find($c_id)
        ->users()
        ->whereId($u_id)
        ->with('positions')
        ->get();
```

And the check is performed within the model itself.

Comment: It makes sense when you use m-m relationship between 3 models again. It seems that you can't query `User`'s `Position` without context of the `Client`, deosn't it?

Comment: Yes, but since I have already queried it with the `$c_id`, and the `$u_id`, I was trying to access that information from `$this` inside the relation, and then constraint the returned values.

Comment: A User can have more than one Position at one Client?

Comment: Yes, a User can multiple Positions at any given Client.

Comment: Then ignore my previous suggestion and check the answer

Comment: Seriously @LaravelMG? You edit my post to remove "Thanks" to get your name on it?

Comment: @kousha: All his suggestions is reviewed due to his low rep. He just follows the S.O [directive](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/744588) on "fluff". You can revert it anyway if that does hurts you. Keep cool :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this, but it won't work when eager loading, because obviously `$id` won't be accessible:

```
// Client model
public function usersWithPositions()
{
    $id = $this->getKey();

    return $this->belongsToMany('User')->with(['positions' => function ($q) use ($id) {
        $q->whereClientId($id);
    }]); 
}

// will work
$client = Client::find($c_id);
$client->usersWithPositions;
// or
$Mike = $client->usersWithPositions()->where('users.id', $u_id)->first();


// won't work
Client::with('usersWithPositions')->get();
```

You can add check to this method, so it doesn't throw exception, but still it won't work with eager loading.